# No Database selected

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
include 'connect.php';

        $sql = "SELECT 
                    user_id,
                    user_name,
                    user_level
                FROM
                    users
                WHERE
                    user_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "'
                AND
                    user_pass = '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result)
        {

            echo 'Something went wrong while signing in. Please try again later.';
            //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
        }
```

Can someone please have a look at this and fix the error.
This is the error: No Database selected.
I took signin.php from an online tutorial which might be outdated. It would help if someone told me if it would be ok to keep $server as localhost. Please remember that I'm new to programming and may make basic mistakes.
This is connect.php:
It works, I've tested it with signup.php

```
<?php
//connect.php
$server = 'localhost';
$username   = 'xxx';
$password   = 'xxx';
$database   = 'xxx';
$mysqli = new mysqli("$server", "$username", "$password", "$database");
if(!mysqli_connect($server, $username,  $password))
{
exit('Error: could not establish database connection');
}
?>
```

Comment: You are mixing [MySQL](http://php.net/book.mysql) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/book.mysqli) functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the $database in the `mysqli_connect`

```
if(!mysqli_connect($server, $username,  $password, $database))
```

And there is no need for this line since you don't use this variable in your code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("$server", "$username", "$password", "$database");
```

Comment: Now it says: Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\signin.php on line 69

Comment: It is telling you that you're calling a variable that is not yet defined. Check if you have declared any ``$sql`` before this line.

Comment: Yes in:  
            $sql = "SELECT 
                        user_id,
                        user_name,
                        user_level
                    FROM
                        users
                    WHERE
                        user_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "'
                    AND
                        user_pass = '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "'";

Comment: Can you paste this signin.php file in http://pastebin.com/ so I can check what is wrong?

Comment: Here http://pastebin.com/1pVpQa5u

Comment: You didn't paste all the code, it is only showing the first 60 lines

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9u078J8M

Comment: The only problem I see here is that you are mixing mysql and mysqli functions. Try to change all the ``mysql`` calls into ``mysqli``

Comment: What parameters do I need for mysqli_query?

Comment: Save your connection into a variable and do this ``$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);``

Comment: got that, but what does: "Error unexpected end of file" mean?

Comment: Means the php didn't expected the file to end, it was expecting more code. It may be a problem with your if's and else's... check them.

Comment: I can't find the problem, can you have a look please.

Comment: please tell me when you've figured it out

Comment: I've figure out the main problem of this question. Without more information I can't figure out what is going on just by you telling me an error. You can open another question if you want more help.

Comment: There is a notice before I post saying my questions haven't been well received. I don't want to ask another bad question. The error is on line 108. Do you know any other site where doing this sort of posting code and asking for help is allowed?

Answer (score 0):

In connect.php you connect with the Mysqli extension, so you should use this in your script:

```
$result= mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```